# Java: how to execute a process which is not attached to a Windows console?

Tags: java, process, console

Both, *Runtime.exec()* as well as *ProcessBuilder* seem to attach a console to the started process. On Windows 7, one can see a *conhost.exe* popping up in the Task Manager. My problem is now that the C process I'm trying to start performs following test to determine whether it has a console window to which it can issue prompts:

```
HANDLE cons = CreateFile("CONOUT$", GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (cons != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
   // Prompt user; this makes my application hang
}
```

**Is it possible with Java to start the C process in a way that upper test fails in order to avoid the prompt?**

Comment: In win32 you call CreateProcess with the  CREATE_NO_WINDOW
 creation flag

Comment: This may not be the solution you're looking for, but _Runtime.exec()_ returns a `Process` object. Can't you use the process' input stream to interact with it? Then you can probably send what the program needs to be "unhanged".

Comment: @David Using CreateProcess will require native code -- either JNI or JNA. Given that I still need to read the output of the C process, that could make things rather complex. Hence, I was looking for a pure Java solution.

Comment: Agreed. I was offering something in case there was no pure Java solution.

Comment: @Executifs In my case, the process is Git resp. SSH which may ask for passwords, validity of server fingerprint's etc. One problem is that (at least certain) prompts are done using _getch which I couldn't pipe at all. But overall, parsing output and piping input looks too fragile to me.

Comment: @Marc I've seen sysadmins use [Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to deal with git authentication in a scripting context. SSH auth through certificates may solve your problem if you're running in a controlled environment.

Comment: How about writing your own executable process in C that then runs the process you need without the console? It's not pure Java again, but at least it doesn't use JNI/JNA.

Comment: How do you start this process from outside Java so that it doesn't detect the output stream? David mentioned CREATE_NO_WINDOW - is that the only way? FWIW, I wouldn't write the C app this way. Most apps use the presence of command-line arguments to determine whether to prompt the user for input. Why not follow that precedent?

Answer (score 1):

At least on OpenJDK 6, [CreateProcess is being called with CREATE_NO_WINDOW](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/b139627f7bc3/src/windows/native/java/lang/ProcessImpl_md.c).  I would imagine that the Sun JDK's code is pretty similar.  This makes me wonder if something else is causing that console to be present. Have you tried running your program with javaw.exe instead of java.exe?

Thinking outside of the box, maybe [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/) is a better way to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd", "/C start /B myprogram.exe param1 param2" );
```

The `/B` flag tells `start` to not create a new console, though I don't know whether or not `start` itself will end up allocating a console when called from Java.

Comment: Sounds interesting; however trying to run "start" gives me "CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified". Also, I couldn't find any "start" executable in C:\Windows.

Comment: My mistake - start is a shell command, not a program. Updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that still does not work. CreateFile("CONOUT$", ...) still returns no INVALID_HANDLE, GetConsoleTitle() gives "GetConsoleTitle" and even 2(!) conhost.exe processes are started.

Comment: Have you tried running your program with "< NUL" to see if that will kill the input stream?

Comment: I have tried that from command line, still it detects a console attached.

Comment: You mentioned above that you're interacting with Git. Have you explored using a Java Git library instead of talking to the command-line client?

Answer (score 0):

Using Runtime is tricky cause you need to consume the output and input with streams.. See this article:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Instead try using the exec library of apache commons.. Here's something that will get you started:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: AFAIU, Apache commons exec library also uses Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), so the problem remains (see org.apache.commons.exec.launcher package). The link you gave is wrong, btw.